# Laravel 5 middlewear doesn't work on Route::group

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

So I have a route group as defined below:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/api/v2', 'middlewear' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::resource(...);
    //more routes defined here
});
```

Then when I run `php artisan route:list` from within the homestead box, I get all my routes, however no middlewear is being applied.  If I then hit the route in the browser I'm not redirected to the login view as I would when the auth middlewear is being applied.  If I move the middlewear definition to the controller's `__construct` then it works.  Any idea why defining the middlewear in the route group doesn't work in laravel 5, or what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo, try middleware, see below

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware

Comment: I'm an idiot, and you are correct.  Thank you for pointing that out :) As soon as I can accept the answer I will.

Comment: been there before, no worries ;)